# Attempting to create a rule that triggers upon a camera being plugged in via usb

Tags: usb, udev, camera

I'm been trying to get a rule to trigger when plugging in my camera(eos r) to further automate photo importing and the like, but I cant get the initial rule to trigger. I'm new to linux in general & am using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

lsusb yields this information
`Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04a9:32da Canon, Inc. Canon Digital Camera`

The rule
*/etc/udev/rules.d/91-camerabackup.rules*

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04a9", ATTRS{idProduct}=="32da", RUN+="/home/thele/photo_backup.sh"
```

I've tried using chmod
`chmod 0644 /etc/udev/rules.d/91-camerabackup.rules`

I've tried various times to reboot or use `udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger`

The bash script resides in */home/thele/photo_backup.sh*. Just executing `bash /home/thele/photo_backup.sh` creates a folder.

```
echo "Do Folder Camera Stuff"
mkdir camshelltest
```

I assume that this is enough to test out whether the rule works. What else I am missing? Or is there any other way to approach this?

Comment: Does `/home/thele/photo_backup.sh` have an appropriate shebang, and is it executable (i.e. can you run `/home/thele/photo_backup.sh` **without** the explicit `bash` command)?

Comment: ok just briefly learned of this, added ```#!/bin/bash``` to the top of the script and used ```chmod +x photo_backup.sh``` on it. ```/home/thele/photo_backup.sh``` runs without the explicit bash command, and creates a folder but the rule itself still does trigger when plugging the camera in again.

Comment: Where did you check for the folder? remember that `mkdir camshelltest` will create a directory wherever the working directory of the rule is (likely the filesystem root, `/`). Likewise, remember that `echo "Do Folder Camera Stuff"` won't have a terminal to echo the string *to*.

Comment: Use `mkdir $HOME/camshelltest`.

Comment: thanks guys! not sure how to mark this as answered but the folder was being made in the root instead of where I was expecting it to be. I am also assuming making it executable helped things, and finally fixed my script to be an absolute path rather than a relative one.